# Returning information if vehicle is available

Tags: java

I want `getStatus` method to return a message saying the vehicle is free if its at null or has reached its destination.. but i get an error Incompatible types i am not sure whats wrong with my if statement.. i am quiet new to programming, so i am sorry if my code is completely wrong

```
 /**
     * Return the status of this Vehicle.
     * @return The status.
     */
    public String getStatus()
    {
            return id + " at " + location + " headed for " +
           destination;
           if (destination = null) {
               System.out.println("This Vehicle is free");
            }
            else if (location=destination) {
                System.out.println ("This Vehicle is free");
            }

    }
```

Comment: I'm suggesting you to read some basic java tutorial.

Comment: if (location=destination). Isn't it should be == ?

Comment: this should give compile time error. because its never come to if statement. its is unreachable statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code give compile time error unreachable statement. 
should both destination and location in same type.

```
public String getStatus() {

if (destination == null) {
System.out.println("This Vehicle is free");
}
else if (location == destination) {
System.out.println ("This Vehicle is free");
}
return id + " at " + location + " headed for " + destination;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return id + " at " + location + " headed for " +
           destination;   // code after this statement is unreachable...
```

1. You will get unreachable code error... Your return should be the last statement to execute.
2. if (destination = null) is wrong.. It should be  if (destination == null). '=' assigns values. '==' compares.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(destination = null)
```

will always return true because `=` is used for assignmnet

Use `==` for comparison

```
if (destination == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you do a return, anything underneath it will not be executed. You need to do the return at the end.

`location=destination`

and

`destination = null`

are wrong because = is assignment, what you want is == which is comparison for equality.

```
public String getStatus()
{
    if (destination == null) {
        System.out.println("This Vehicle is free");
    }
    else if (location == destination) {
        System.out.println("This Vehicle is free");
    }

    return (id + " at " + location + " headed for " + destination);
}
```